# How can I use an Html file in a raw Android folder to populate a Xamarin Forms webview?

Tags: android, html, file, webview, xamarin.forms

I have an html file saved on an Android device here:

/data/data/MyApp.Mobile.Forms/files/4650-0/11456.pptx.html

I'm able to use FileReaders to look at the Html. However when I set it as my webViews HTML source, like so:

```
var path = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.pptx.html")[0];
string htmlString = File.ReadAllText(path);

var htmlWebViewSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlWebViewSource.Html = @htmlString;
htmlWebViewSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();

webView.Source = htmlWebViewSource;
```

I get an activity indicator but no webview loads. I've tested other sites, e.g. Google, and raw html, and these work. But for some reason, my html does not.

I've also seen other approaches using stream readers, but none of these have worked for me.

I see a lot of talk of my html file needs to be in the assets folder. But the file is saved at runtime and files can't be saved to assets at runtime.

Please help me work out what I'm missing here. Can I have a webview using a file from that data/data path?